# Why is the "Software" application not showing the same results as "Software Updates" or even apt?

Tags: package-management, updates, gnome-software

I open the "Software" application, go to "Updates" and click the refresh button. The GUI shows this:

[image: Software GUI]

I open "Software Updater", let it refresh, and it shows:

[image: Software Updates]

On the command line:

```
~ • apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
fsearch-trunk/artful 0.1+355+9~ubuntu17.10.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.1+354+9~ubuntu17.10.1]
google-chrome-stable/stable 65.0.3325.162-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 65.0.3325.146-1]
```

So... there *are* updates available. Searching for "FSearch" in the Software application shows no option to update:

[image]

The Software app also seems to be unable to find newer versions of repository software in PPAs or internal repositories. For example, even with the Virtualbox repository in my `sources.list.d/`, searching for "virtualbox" in Software only returns the package in the official repository, whereas:

```
~ • apt list virtualbox*
Listing... Done
virtualbox/artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64
virtualbox-5.1/unknown 5.1.34-121010~Ubuntu~zesty amd64
virtualbox-5.2/unknown 5.2.8-121009~Ubuntu~zesty amd64
virtualbox-dkms/artful,artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 all
virtualbox-ext-pack/artful,artful 5.1.30-2 all
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/artful,artful 5.1.30-1 all
virtualbox-guest-dkms/artful,artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 all
virtualbox-guest-source/artful,artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 all
virtualbox-guest-utils/artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64
virtualbox-guest-x11/artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64
virtualbox-qt/artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 amd64
virtualbox-source/artful,artful 5.1.30-dfsg-1 all
```

Why? What is this app meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Software is for modern Android/iOS entertainment-oriented newbies, not for techies and old-school users. Such users need only games, YouTube and media-player. They do not need `build-essential`, `texlive`, development packages and so on. They need only to play, consume and watch :)

You can read [some thoughts about software installation in modern Ubuntus on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/software-installation-on-modern-ubuntu/2555).
At present time the best are `aptitude`, `apt`, Muon and Synaptic.

Comment: [Synaptic won't work under Wayland](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1731324) without poking holes in security, so that's one less option as Ubuntu moves from X to Wayland.

Comment: As you may know - [18.04 LTS will be shipped with Xorg by default](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default). I know about pkexec'ed applications and su-to-root bugs ([1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311)), as  I reported both of them :)